# REAGENTC.EXE thinks i have bitlocker encryption enabled but the Mange BitLocker control panel dialog does not think it's enabled?

Tags: windows-11, bitlocker, windows-11-v22h2

I was trying to do a factory restore on my laptop and was getting a "Could Not Find the Recovery Environment" error. A Google search suggested I run `reagentc/enable` on the command line to fix this. When I did that I got this error:

```
REAGENTC.EXE: Windows RE cannot be enabled on a volume with BitLocker Drive Encryption enabled.
```

Not realizing I had BitLocker Drive Encryption enabled I tried to disable it. Only to discover that it's not enabled?:

[image]

So some Windows programs think BitLocker Drive Encryption is enabled and some don't? I suppose that's neither here nor there - all I want to do is to just want `reagentc/enable`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message
"Windows (C:) BitLocker waiting for activation"
means that `C:` is indeed encrypted, but that the
Full Volume Encryption Key (FVEK) that encrypted the data
was saved to disk in plaintext.

If you want to remove BitLocker without activating it, use:

```
manage-bde c: -off
```

For more information see the post
[Is a volume with BitLocker "Waiting for Activation" encrypted or not?](https://superuser.com/questions/1299600/is-a-volume-with-bitlocker-waiting-for-activation-encrypted-or-not)