# Why is my Windows drive appearing as encrypted in Linux (Ubuntu)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-11, bootloader

Why is my Windows 11 installation drive shown as encrypted in Linux GUI when we want to simply mount the drive, when there are following points to note?

1. [BitLocker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitLocker) is *disabled*
2. Data encryption is not enabled.
3. [Norton AntiVirus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norton_AntiVirus) is there, but it does not show any encryption-related stuff.
4. Windows has a Local Administrator enabled (I have access).

I tried following Linux distributions for double checking.

- [Ubuntu 22.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_22.04_LTS_(Jammy_Jellyfish)) (Jammy Jellyfish) (Liveboot)
- [Kali Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kali_Linux) (Liveboot)

Screenshots are following for some of the commands highlighted in comments.

[image]

[image]

The output of the command `manage-bde -status C:` is the following:

```
cd C:\Windows\System32
manage-bde -status C:
```

Output:

```
BitLocker Drive Encryption: Configuration Tool version 10.0.22621
Copyright (C) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Volume C: []
[OS Volume]

    Size:                 476.21 GB
    BitLocker Version:    2.0
    Conversion Status:    Used Space Only Encrypted
    Percentage Encrypted: 100.0%
    Encryption Method:    XTS-AES 128
    Protection Status:    Protection Off
    Lock Status:          Unlocked
    Identification Field: Unknown
    Key Protectors:       None Found
```

I just either need my drive normally accessible as other drives are or need to extract that secret for decryption if possible.

Comment: "drive is shown as encrypted in Linux" – Where exactly? Please [edit] and post the exact command plus its output (as text) that makes you believe your Linux finds the drive encrypted. Or if this information comes from a GUI tool, post a screenshot.

Comment: No command simple GUI and when i click "mount" it asks for passphrase also the icon of the drive is showing a small lock

Comment: Run `lsblk`, identify the name of the drive in question (e.g. `sdb`) and its partitions (e.g. `sdb1`, `sdb2`, …). For each of these run `sudo file -skr /dev/name` (where you need to substitute `name` with the actual name); post each command and its output in the body of the question.

Comment: Updated the question @KamilMaciorowski

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/108618). Post text as text.

Comment: Can you show the output of `manage-bde -status C:` from Windows? It seems like it's BitLocker in the "clear key" mode, which cryptsetup doesn't yet recognize.

Comment: question updated @u1686_grawity

Comment: Can you post the terminal session as text instead of an image, please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yes sure when I will login to ubuntu as I use both Windows & Linux for my tasks

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714)

Comment: [Related](https://superuser.com/questions/1299600/is-a-volume-with-bitlocker-waiting-for-activation-encrypted-or-not) thread.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You do in fact have a BitLocker-encrypted disk – it's in a "dormant" or "clear key" mode, where the disk directly stores its own decryption key so there's no passphrase or anything. (This has the advantage of reducing cleartext data to the minimum should you ever decide to enable BitLocker in the future.)

Currently Linux cryptsetup does not yet support this mode, but you might be able to access the volume using the older tools, either `dislocker` or `bdemount` (the latter from "libbde") – they aren't integrated into the graphical file manager, but have more extensive support of various BitLocker configurations.

You also can fully decrypt the disk by disabling BitLocker using `bde-manage -off`.

Comment: Thanks a lot this resolved my issue, Bitlocker was the issue after applying the command bde-manage -off my disk is now accessible